# Headphones noise

Tags: sound

I plug in my headphones I start hearing an hissing noise coming from them. The noise is continuous and doesn't changhe in intensity when I turn up or down the volume, but it stops when I lower it completely or mute it. Also, if the laptop is plugged in and I unplug it, the noise stops even if the pc gets plugged back in, but it starts back again as soon as a sound is played. I found several similar problems posted by other Ubuntu users, but none of those was the same as mine, and none of the solutions posted worked for me. I have an HP Pavilion 15-p258nl, dual boot with Windows 10 (no problems there).

Sound card:

```
 *-multimedia:0          
   description: Audio device
   product: Broadwell-U Audio Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 3
   bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
   version: 09
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
   resources: irq:54 memory:c6210000-c6213fff
 *-multimedia:1
   description: Audio device
   product: Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1b
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
   version: 03
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=64
   resources: irq:52 memory:c6214000-c6217fff
```

Comment: Some extra details would be helpful I guess, like laptop & sound card model.

Comment: You're right, sorry, added

Comment: Does you AC adapter have a ground pin.This happens on laptops without the ground pin

Comment: Yes, it has a ground pin. As i said, the noise is still there even if the laptop is not charging.